# Double Conversion to decimal value IEEE-754 in Python

Tags: python, double, decimal, ieee-754

I am trying to convert my `double` type data 64 bits long to decimal value. I am following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format
for the converting.

I have tried it in following script:

```
a = '\x3f\xd5\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55'  # Hexbyte representation of 1/3 value in double

sign_bit =  bin(ord(a[0])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0')[0]
sign = -1 ** int(sign_bit)
print sign    # Sign bit

# Next 11 bits for exponent calculation
exp_bias = 1023
a11 = bin(ord(a[0])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0')[1:] + bin(ord(a[1])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0')[:4]
exp = int(a11, 2)
print exp

# Next 52 bits for fraction calculation
fraction = bin(ord(a[1])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0')[4:] + bin(ord(a[2])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0') \
           + bin(ord(a[3])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0') + bin(ord(a[4])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0') \
            + bin(ord(a[5])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0') + bin(ord(a[6])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0') \
            + bin(ord(a[7])).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0')
print len(fraction), fraction
fract = str(int(fraction, 2))
print len(fract), fract
fin = repr(float(fract)/ 10 ** 16)
print type(fin), fin   # 16 digit precision

# final value calculation according equation 
# eq = (-1)^sign * 2 ^(exp- exp_bias) * (1 + fin)
val = 2 ** (exp - exp_bias) * float(fin)    # Looses precision
print val
```

Please, any one help me out with this. I am not able understand where I am wrong? Cause I can have fraction value with precision by using `repr()` but whenever try to use it into equation, it looses its precision in `float()`.

Is there anyway or alternate way to solve it?

Comment: Your code can be much simpler if you use [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray)

Comment: If possible do not work with strings as long as possible but with integers. Eg `sign_bit=bytearray(a)[0]>>7` Also if  possible do not use float as you lose precision on most float operations.

Comment: @janbrohl Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually if your problem is just about bytes-to decimal representation (not about implementing yourself) then you can use [struct](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html) with `val=struct.unpack(">d",a)[0]` - this is also helpful for checking how much precision you actualy lose

Comment: @janbrohl Yes. It is my partial problem to represent bytes-to decimal representation. Let's say i want to use this precise number into some calculation than how could I?

Comment: It is propably even easier if you convert `a` to a `long` right at the start and do [bit-operations](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) on it. `bigint=int(a.encode("hex"),16)` and for the sign-bit: `sign_bit=1&(bigint>>53)`

Comment: @janbrohl Could provide me snippet for this? `bigint=int(a.encode("hex"),16)` return me `4599676419421066581`.

Comment: `struct.unpack` returns the exact `double` value represented by the bytes. (Python `float` is wrapped C `double`) - if you dont want precision loss in further calculations have a look at [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fractions.html) (no loss on `+-*/`)  and [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html) (set the exact needed precision yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do this conversion is to use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.

```
from struct import unpack

a = '\x3f\xd5\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55'
n = unpack('>d', a)
print '%.18f' % n[0]
```

**output**

```
0.33333333333333331
```

In Python 3, you need to specify the input string and the packing format string as byte strings, eg

```
a = b'\x3f\xd5\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55'
n = unpack(b'>d', a)
print(format(n[0], '.18f'))
```

You can also use the `b` string prefix in Python 2 (from 2.6 and later, IIRC). Python 2 just ignores that prefix, since normal Python 2 strings are bytes strings.

Comment: Thank you. It feels stupid of me to not to think about this. But, still if I want to use this `n` into some calculation than what can be done?

Comment: @abhi1610 The `struct.unpack` function returns a tuple, since it can be used to unpack multiple data items from a string. And that's why I used  `n[0]` to access the value of the `float` object. Python `float`s are standard [IEEE-754 double precision 64 bit binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Too much work.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>d', '\x3f\xd5\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55')[0]
0.3333333333333333
```